# How do I shift array characters to the right in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, shift

This is what I have:

```
class encoded
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s1 = "hello";
        char[] ch = s1.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
        {
            char c = (char) (((i - 'a' + 1) % 26) + 'a');
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

So far I've converted the string to an array, and I've worked out how to shift, but now I'm stuck.

What I want is for the code to start at `ch[0]`, read the character, shift it one to the right (`h` to `i`) and then do the same for each character in the array until it reaches the end.

Right now, my code outputs `opqrs`. I want it to output `ifmmp`. If I replace the `int i = 0` in the `for` loop with `int i = ch[0]`, it does start at `i`, but then it just inputs `ijklmno...`

I want it to read `h`, output as `i`, read `e`, output as `f`, and so on until it reaches the end of the array.

Comment: Think about what you are doing. What is the purpose of the variable `i`?  Where  are the characters stored  that you want to "shift"?

Answer (score 5):

You are using the loop index `i` instead of the `i`th character in your loop, which means the output of your code does not depend the input `String` (well, except for the length of the output, which is the same as the length of the input).

Change

```
char c = (char) (((i - 'a' + 1) % 26) + 'a');
```

to

```
char c = (char) (((ch[i] - 'a' + 1) % 26) + 'a');
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you please explain what changed between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `i - 'a' + 1` with `ch[i] - 'a' + 1`

```
class encoded {

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     String s1 = "hello";
     char[] ch = s1.toCharArray();
     for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
     { 
        char c = (char) (((ch[i] - 'a' + 1) % 26) + 'a');
        System.out.print(c);
     }
   }
}
```